# Getting data from Website table into excel through vba

Tags: excel, vba, web

I trying to get the information from the website and sucessfully getting this using this code:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://www.theconstructionindex.co.uk" & Range("URL_code").Value
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.document
Dim sDD As String
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(1).innerText
Range("b2").Value = sDD
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(3).innerText
Range("b3").Value = sDD
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(5).innerText
Range("b4").Value = sDD
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(7).innerText
Range("b5").Value = sDD
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(9).innerText
Range("b6").Value = sDD
sDD = doc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(11).innerText
Range("b7").Value = sDD
```

The problem is that each time I hit button and code runs it slows down the computer. I sure that it is memory management issue. Can anyone suggest how to free the RAM used by this code each time it runs?

Comment: How many Internet Explorers are opened currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not closing the instances of Internet Explorer. They are invisible (`IE.Visible = False`), thus you do not see them, but they are there and they are eating RAM. This is a possible solution:

- Close all your InternetExplorer Instances, by selecting `TaskManager > Processes > InternetExplorer > Right Mouse Button > End Task` (or restart your PC);
- Then close each instance of `IE` once you stop working with it. Like this:

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    'do something here
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I automatically copy all the data from this website as the data is in tables. https://www.theconstructionindex.co.uk/planning-leads/16   the page is 16 then 17 then 18 and so on.. any solution that I hit button and all pages data into excel sheet. ?